# Reference value from positional element in array in update

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "urls": {
                "a": "url-a",
                "b": "url-b",
                "c": "url-c"
            },
            "revisions": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to add a new object to the `revisions` array that contains its own `urls` field. Two of the fields should be copied from the entry's `urls`, while the last one will be new. The result should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "urls": {
                "a": "url-a",
                "b": "url-b",
                "c": "url-c"
            },
            "revisions": [
                {
                    "id": 1000,
                    "urls": {
                        "a": "url-a", <-- copied
                        "b": "url-b", <-- copied
                        "c": "some-new-url" <-- new
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am on MongoDB 4.2+, so I know I can use `$property` on the update query to reference  values. However, this does not seem to be working as I expect:

```
collection.updateOne(
    {
        id: 1,
        "enntries.id": 100 
    },
    {
        $push: {
            "entries.$.revisions": {
                id: 1000,
                urls: {
                    "a": "$entries.$.urls.a",
                    "b": "$entries.$.urls.b",
                    "c": "some-new-url"
                }
            } 
        }       
    }
);
```

The element gets added to the array, but all I see for the url values is the literal `$entries.$.urls.a`. value I suspect the issue is with combining the reference with selecting a specific positional array element. I have also tried using `$($entries.$.urls.a)`, with the same result.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You've few issues with query, So `entires` is an array, Do you want to do it on every object in entires array or for few or for only first one ?

Comment: I want to do it exactly for the one that matches the `entries.id`, so I believe what I have is correct. That part is behaving as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB version >= `4.2` you can use aggregation pipeline in updates which means your update part of query will be wrapped in `[]` where you can take advantage of executing aggregation in query & also use existing field values in updates.

**Issue :**

Since you've not wrapped update part in `[]` to say it's an aggregation pipeline, `.updateOne()` is considering `"$entries.$.urls.a"` as a string. I believe you'll not be able to use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) positional operator in updates which use aggregation pipeline.

**Try below query which uses aggregation pipeline :**

```
collection.updateOne(
  {
    id: 1,
    "entries.id": 100 /** "entries.id" is optional but much needed to avoid execution of below aggregation for doc where `id :1` but no `"entries.id": 100` */,
  } 
  [
    {
      $set: {
        entries: {
          $map: { // aggregation operator `map` iterate over array & creates new array with values.
            input: "$entries",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.id", 100] }, // `$$this` is current object in array iteration, if condition is true do below functionality for that object else return same object as is to array being created.
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      revisions: { $concatArrays: [ "$$this.revisions", [{ id: 1000, urls: { a: "$$this.urls.a", b: "$$this.urls.b", c: "some-new-url" } } ]] }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "$$this" // Returning same object as condition is not met.
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

`$mergeObjects` will replace existing `revisions` field in `$$this` (current) object with value of `{ $concatArrays: [ "$$this.revisions", { id: 1000, urls: { a: "$$this.urls.a", b: "$$this.urls.b", c: "some-new-url" } } ] }`.

From the above field name `revisions` and as it being an array I've assumed there will multiple objects in that field & So we're using `$concatArrays` operator to push new objects into `revisions` array of particular `entires` object.

In any case, if your `revisions` array field does only contain one object make it as an object instead of array Or you can keep it as an array & use below query - We've removed `$concatArrays` cause we don't need to merge new object to existing `revisions` array as we'll only have one object every-time.

```
collection.update(
  {
    id: 1,
    "entries.id": 100
  } 
  [
    {
      $set: {
        entries: {
          $map: {
            input: "$entries",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.id", 100] },
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      revisions:  [ { id: 1000, urls: { a: "$$this.urls.a", b: "$$this.urls.b", c: "some-new-url" } } ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

**Test :** Test your aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iljr8ONb3FO)

**Ref :** [.updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)

**Note :** If in any case `.updateOne()` throws in an error due to in-compatible client or shell, try this query with `.update()`. This execution of aggregation pipeline in updates helps to save multiple DB calls & can be much useful on arrays with less no.of elements.

Comment: This is an amazingly complete answer, I appreciate you taking the time. Everything works flawlessly!